# GDAL 3.0.4 invalid coordinate transformation result

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to transform coordinates from a modified EPSG:31255 CRS (false northing +y_0 = 0) to EPSG:31255 (false northing +y_0 = -5000000) and always get a wrong result using GDAL 3.0.4.
The transformation should remove 5000000 in y, but reverses xy as well.

With GDAL 2.4.0 everything works as expected.

```
Custom EPSG: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.3333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs

EPSG 31255: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.3333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs
```

```
from osgeo import osr,ogr
wkt = 'POLYGON((32611 5320163,32611 5337745,54270 5337745,54270 5320163,32611 5320163))'
srs = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.3333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs'
trs = 31255

src = osr.SpatialReference()
src.ImportFromProj4(srs)
tgt = osr.SpatialReference()
tgt.ImportFromEPSG(trs)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(src,tgt)
polygon = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
polygon.Transform(transform)
print(polygon.ExportToWkt())
```

Do I miss something here? Is there any Config Setting that prevents this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the definition of EPSG:31255 http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31255 the official axis order is northing-easting.

Read the migration guide https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT
and try this:

```
 OSRImportFromEPSG() takes into account official axis order.
 Traditional GIS-friendly axis order can be restored with
 OGRSpatialReference::SetAxisMappingStrategy(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ...very useful information. tgt.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osgeo.osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER) did the trick.