# Gdal.warp outputs black image when cutting from json

Tags: python, geojson, gdalwarp

I have the following task: to cut a polygon out of an .tif file.

my task is to: **create a new image from the polygons I have**
I perform the following steps:

1. get image and polygon data
2. reproject polygon to EPSG:4326 for json standard
3. make json
4. get polygon's reprojected bounds
5. crop image via gdal.warp

```
geom.Transform(transform)
json_ap = geom.ExportToJson()

gx_min, gx_max, gy_min, gy_max = geom.GetEnvelope()

output_options = gdal.WarpOptions(cutlineDSName = json_ap,
                                    outputBounds= [gx_min,
                                                    gy_min,
                                                    gx_max,
                                                    gy_max],
                                    srcSRS = g_ref,
                                    dstSRS='EPSG:4326',
                                    cropToCutline=True)

gdal.Warp('teste.tif', raster_path, options=output_options)
```

All images I export are blank!

I tried to create the crop with no reprojection, with a different reprojection, with a reprojected tif as source...

What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps the issue may be due to earlier steps, would you be able to elaborate further on them to confirm.

Comment: @whyzar I just figured it out. Check the answer, but it was due to the ogr or osr library.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

One of the following functions may be causing this issue:

geom.Transform(transform) or geom.ExportToJson()

The Json has reversed latitude and longitude values. I wrote the following function in my python script that solved it.

```
def json_latlon_correction(json_file):
    json_file = json.loads(json_file)
    for i in range(len(json_file["coordinates"][0])):
        coord_pair = json_file["coordinates"][0][i]
        json_file["coordinates"][0][i] = coord_pair[::-1]
    return json_file
```

They even have a github issue about this:

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1974

Comment: Is it about the same problem than in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364943/gdal-3-0-4-invalid-coordinate-transformation-result/364947#364947? Perhaps `tgt.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osgeo.osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)` could have helped you as well.